# Cakephp 2.0 Authentication using email instead of username

Tags: cakephp-2.0, authentication

In my view I have:

```
<?php
echo $this->Form->create('User', array("controller" => "Users", "action" => "login", "method" => "post"));
echo $this->Form->input('User.email', array("label" => false));
echo $this->Form->input('User.password', array("label" => false, 'class' => 'password-input'));
echo $this->Form->end(); ?>
```

In my AppController:

```
public $components = array(
        'Session',
        'Auth'
    );

    function beforeFilter(){
        $this->Auth->fields = array(
            'username' => 'email',
            'password' => 'password'
        );
    }
```

In my UsersController:

```
function beforeFilter(){
        $this->Auth->allow('sign_up', 'login', 'logout', 'forgot_password');
        return parent::beforeFilter();
    }
public function login() {
        if ($this->Auth->login()) {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('Successfully logged in'), 'default', array('class' => 'success'));
            $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirect());
        } else {
            if (!empty($this->request->data)) {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('Username or password is incorrect'), 'default', array('class' => 'notice'));
            }
        }
    }
```

But the login is not working, what am I missing?

Thanks.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I believe the problem is:

```
function beforeFilter(){
    $this->Auth->fields = array(
        'username' => 'email',
        'password' => 'password'
    );
}
```

That was how custom login fields were specified in CakePHP 1.3.  CakePHP 2.0 instead requires you to specify these fields in the `public $components = array(...);`.  The [1.3 API](http://api.cakephp.org/1.3/class-AuthComponent.html) shows that Auth has a $fields property, but the [2.0 API](http://api.cakephp.org/2.0/class-AuthComponent.html) shows that there is no longer a $fields property.  So you must:

```
public $components = array(
    'Session',
    'Auth' => array(
        'authenticate' => array(
            'Form' => array(
                'fields' => array('username' => 'email')
            )
        )
    )
);
```

More information can be found at: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html#configuring-authentication-handlers

Please tell me how it works out!

Answer (score 0):

Final solution for my problem. Thank you.

I had a problem with userModel and I write this:

```
'Auth' => array(
         'userModel' => 'Member'
      )
```

instead of this:

```
'Auth' => array(
    'authenticate' => array(
        'Form' => array(
            'userModel' => 'Member'
        )
    )
)
```