# Login With Email instead of username in cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp-2.4

Hai i am new to the cakephp.I have designed login page and signup page using CakePhp.I have been added 2 to 3users information in the users table.Now i want to login with register user Email and password.How can i login with email instead of username using authentication?.I am using the cakephp version 2.4.2.Can u please help me?Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10248333/cakephp-2-0-authentication-using-email-instead-of-username ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17120252/using-email-instead-of-username-in-cakephp-auth-component

Comment: Thanks for your response.Is this code work in version 2.4.2?

Comment: If you never shoot, it will always be a miss.

Answer (score 0):

[Possible duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17120252/using-email-instead-of-username-in-cakephp-auth-component)

Try configure it with:

```
public $components = array(
    'Auth' => array(
        'authenticate' => array(
            'Form' => array(
                'fields' => array('username' => 'email')
            )
        )
    )
);
```

See also [Configuring Authentication handlers](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html#configuring-authentication-handlers) in the cookbook.

All Credits to: [dhofstet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/68234/dhofstet)

Answer (score 0):

Auth is probably one of the most confusing parts of CakePHP when first introduced,
You need to change 'username'=>'username' to 'username'=>'email'

Below is a snippet out of one of my current projects, we use the email field instead of the username.

**I would also suggest this video on CakePHP 2.0 Auth :** 
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zvwQGZ1BxdM

The Video Tutorials helped me a lot when beginning with CakePHP.

```
public $components = array(
  'Auth' => array(
    'loginAction' => array(
      'controller' => 'user',
      'action' => 'signin'
    ),
    'loginRedirect' => '/',
    'authError' => 'Did you really think you are allowed to see that?',
    'userModel' => 'User',
    'authenticate'=>array(
      'Form'=>array(
        'fields'=>array(
          'username'=>'email',
          'password'=>'password'
        )
      )
    )
  )
);
```